# How to get two value in bootstrap range slider?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, twitter-bootstrap

I want to get the two values in range slider to insert in table using `$_POST[]` in php.

Is it possible not to use javascript? if not, feel free to answer. Thanks

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post">

     <!-- #1 range value set 1-2 -->
     <input id="slide_default" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="5" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="[0,1]" name="" />

     <!-- #2 range value set 3-5 --> 
     <input id="slide_default" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="5" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="[0,1]" name="" />

     <input type="submit" name="btn_submit">    

<form>
```

**EXPECTED ARRAY OUTPUT:**

```
Array ( 
        [0] => 1,2 //#1 range value
        [1] => 3,5 //#2 range value
      )
```

**PHP:**

```
 if(isset($_POST['btn_submit']))
 {
      // code here
  }
```

Comment: What is current output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form method="post">

      <!-- #1 range value set 1-2 -->
      <input name="slide_default[]" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="5" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="[0,1]" />

      <!-- #2 range value set 3-5 --> 
      <input name="slide_default[]" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="5" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="[0,1]"/>

      <input type="submit" name="btn_submit">    

 <form>
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['btn_submit'])) {
    print_r($_POST['slide_default']);
}
```

Though I have not tested it, but I think this should work.